# Kotlin: Element not being appended in the list

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an android app with kotlin, but I am currently facing a strange issue. The function where the issue is this:

```
private fun getName(uids:List<String>):List<String> {
        val nameList = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (uid in uids) {
            Firebase.firestore.collection("users").whereEqualTo("id", uid).get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                    val name = documents.documents[0]["name"] as String
                    println("The name is $name")
                    nameList.add(name)
                    println("The namelist is $nameList")
                }
            println("The data above is $nameList")
        }
        println("The datahere is $nameList")
        return nameList.toList()
    }
```

Here I have a few ids of the user and based on these ids I am fetching the name from the Firebase Cloud Firestore database, the data is successfully being fetched and when I print the `namelist` first time inside the fetching block, an element is being added. However, when I print the `nameList` outside the fetching block, I see that the element does not add. I have attached an image.

[image]

As you can see the element is being added. But after that, the element disappears and the list becomes empty.

[image]

I am really confused as to why this is occurring.

Comment: The `addOnSuccessListener` function takes a callback which is called when the data is downloaded. This happens after the current function has executed with the print statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that you want an async job to act as a sync one. As we know such retrieving data from `firestore` is an async procedure (get attention to `addOnSuccessListener`). So when the function returns `nameList` (as well as the last `println`), it is empty because any of the results from `firestore` has not retrieved yet!

---

As `DocumentReference.get()` returns a `Task` object it's possible to wait on it. So, your function could be something like this:

```
@WorkerThread
private fun getName(uids: List<String>) {
    val nameList = mutableListOf<String>()
    for (uid in uids) {
        val task = Firebase.firestore.collection("users").whereEqualTo("id", uid).get()
        val documentSnapshot = Tasks.await(task)
        val name = documentSnapshot.documents[0]["name"] as String
        nameList.add(name)
    }
    nameList.toList()
}
```

Notice that in this case, you should call this function in a worker thread (not main thread).

Comment: Can you please show me how I can make this async

Comment: Actually, I got an error saying "Must not be called on the main application thread". I have used the exact same code.

Comment: I've mentioned it in the last line of the answer. The simplest way is to run a thread and call this function inside it. For example:  `Thread { val result = getName(...) /* do whatever with the result */ }.start()`